# Trying to setup Python application, odd error

Tags: python

Although python3 cannot find the Cython module:

```
python3 setup.py
Could not import cx_Freeze. Building executable not possible.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 13, in <module>
    from Cython.Build import cythonize
ImportError: No module named 'Cython'
```

pip3 says it has been installed:

```
pip3 install Cython
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Cython in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages
Cleaning up...
```

What is going on? How do I fix this?

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Some more relevant information:
Pip version:

```
pip3 -V
pip 1.5.4 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.4)
```

Python version:

```
python3 -V
Python 3.4.6
```

Tried to install from within Python session:

```
python3
Python 3.4.6 (default, May 11 2017, 18:25:35) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> import Cython
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'Cython'
>>> sys.executable
'/usr/local/bin/python3'
>>> exit()

python3 -m pip install module
/usr/local/bin/python3: No module named pip

python3 -m pip Cython
/usr/local/bin/python3: No module named pip

sudo apt-get install python3-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-pip is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libgsoap4 libvncserver0
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 189 not upgraded.
```

[EDIT]

This problem was a complete mess and I still have no clue what happened before. I have given up trying to get Python to work, as I have found an application that does the same thing as the Python application I was trying to get working. It's such a pain.

Comment: `pip3` and `python3` may not refer to the same interpreter. Try `python3 -m pip install Cython`. This can be confirmed by `which pip3` / `where pip3` (depending on OS) and comparing that path to `/usr/local/lib/python3.4/`

Comment: @DeepSpace It says ```/usr/local/bin/python3: No module named pip```

Comment: check your path data, you may have something weird there.

Comment: @Saelyth Where can I find that?

Comment: Without knowing your SO It's hard to tell but I'll assume you are on windows 7 as example and give you this: http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2009/10/21/how-to-set-the-windows-path-in-windows-7.aspx It should point you to the right direction of where pathing is stored. For a bit of explanation, it's possible that you have different python installations on the same computer, but the pathing will only refer to 1 of them, so if you use the CMD to call a python script that you want to use with an alternative installation it won't work because the CMD will use the wrong path.

Comment: You should research what the pathing is and how it may affect python. When I didn't know about that I had so big of a mess that I had to wipe out entirely everything python related and re-install my libraries properly.

Comment: @Saelyth I'm on Linux Mint Cinnamon 64-bit, not Windows 7. Also, I know nothing about this subject.